# Getting duplicate form while editting item in sp list

Tags: sharepoint

One of the user is getting duplicate form (same two form on one page) while editing item in SP2013 list but for other user it is coming fine.
Could anyone suggest me the cause of it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the form has been customized using InfoPath or SharePoint Designer. If it has, you'll need to examine the form customizations to see what might cause that behavior.

If it has not been customized, try opening the form in a new window and editing the page. There may be duplicate web parts on the page. Audience targeting may be preventing some users (yourself included) from seeing the extra web part.